# I want to center my navigation bar in css

Tags: html, css, center, navigationbar

Since a couple of days I'm working on a navigation bar for my website. But I want to center it and `margin auto` does not work. Here's my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
  <title>Homepage - Trolltime</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS code:

```css
li:hover {font-size:120%}
li:visited{color:black}

ul.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  margin:auto;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-family:Verdana;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
}
ul { list-style-type:none; }
body { background-color:#33CCFF; }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGeg6/)

In html you have used id and in css you have given class to nav. Please see below.

```
ul#nav{
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
margin:0 auto;
width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, here example:

```css
li:hover {font-size:120%}
li:visited{color:black}

ul#nav {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display:inline !important;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-family:Verdana;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
}
ul { list-style-type:none; }
body { background-color:#33CCFF; }
.wrapMenu{ text-align:center; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapMenu">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow idea as below:

```
nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

nav.horizontal {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

nav.horizontal ul {
    display: table-row;
}

nav.horizontal li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for submitting but it doesn't work properly :( I now have the navigation bar centered, but it isn't inline.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

I've changed:

```
ul.nav { 
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

to:

```
ul#nav { text-align: center; }
```

On your `li` you had both `display: inline` and `display: block;`.
So I've deleted: `display: block` and `float: left`, and changed `display: inline` to  `display: inline-block`.

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9nykr/)**</kbd>